# Deploying Create React App on OpenShift: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/node/app/.eslintcache'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, openshift, create-react-app

I'm trying to deploy a Create React App webapp on OpenShift using a Dockerfile. The OpenShift build completes successfully and when I visit the route I'm able to see the application running for 1 second and then this error comes on the screen:

```
Failed to compile
EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/node/app/.eslintcache'
```

I don't understand why the permission denied error is coming because I've assigned the directory permissions needed to the `node` user provided by the node Docker image in my Dockerfile.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM node:14-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app &&\
 chmod -R 775 /home/node/app &&\
 chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json /home/node/app/
USER node
RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . /home/node/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Software versions:
react-scripts 4.0.1
OpenShift 4.2, 4.4, 4.5 (Tried with all)

Here's the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-node-js-application-with-docker) I used as reference and the [source repo](https://github.com/cseas/react-jokes).

---

**Update:**
Thanks to Will Gordon's answer, I was able to figure it out. OpenShift expects you to specify the user ID and not the name. Also, OpenShift runs containers as a random ID belonging to group 0 so permission for that group needs to be specified. Here's the working Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM node:14-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app &&\
 chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app

RUN chgrp -R 0 /home/node/app &&\
 chmod -R g+rwX /home/node/app

COPY package*.json /home/node/app/
USER 1000
RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . /home/node/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: u need to cd into /home/node/app/ before npm install

Comment: Isn't that what `WORKDIR /home/node/app` is for? My Dockerfile is very similar to the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363105/permission-denied-mkdir-in-container-on-openshift).

Further, the Dockerfile gives no errors at build so I'm assuming the permissions are fine. It's the new `.eslintcache` file that latest `react-scripts` versions have started to create is what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting up a specific user and permissions for that user. OpenShift's default configuration is to run containers with a random UID. It's recommended to use the root GID (GID 0) when setting permissions, instead of UIDs, as OpenShift will automatically apply GID 0 to the user.

You can find more guidelines on creating images for OpenShift in the documentation https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I've updated the question with the working Dockerfile.